# Как в скрипте прописать закрытие файла?

Tags: скрипт, файлы, bash

Команда `lsof` выводит имена открытых файлов в настоящий момент. Как написать скрипт, закрывающий все эти файлы? Какая вообще команда/операция используется в скриптах для закрытия файлов?

Answer (score 7):

Вы хотите закрыть файловый дискриптор чужого процесса?
Это странное желание: вы скорее всего вызовите ошибки в процессе, в котором этот дескриптор открыт. Но если очень хочется и вы четко понимаете, что делаете, можете использовать мое решение с использованием gdb (ничего лучше не придумал):

```
#!/bin/sh

pid=$1
fd=$2
commands=$(mktemp "gdb.XXXXXXXXXX")
echo -e "attach $pid\np close($fd)" > $commands
gdb -batch -x $commands > /dev/null
status=$?
rm $commands
exit $status
```

Этот скрипт запускает gdb, делает attach к процессу с pid, переданным в первом аргументе, и закрывает в нем дескриптор, переданный во втором аргументе. Скрипт надо запускать с правами суперпользователя.

### Пример использования.

```
$ cat test.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
    while (1);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc test.c -o test

$ ./test &

$ lsof 2>/dev/null | grep "foo.txt"

test       5904     dzhioev    3w      REG              252,0        0   10884489 /home/dzhioev/foo.txt

$ sudo ./close_fd.sh 5904 3

$ lsof 2>/dev/null | grep "foo.txt"

$ #nothing
```

Comment: Возможно, это хорошее решение, но совершенно не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Ну напишете тогда, что вам нужно. Я написал то, что вы просили.

Comment: @dzhioev Круто.

Answer (score 0):

Очень надеюсь, что я неправильно понял, но закрытие ВСЕХ файлов, показанных после использования `lsof`, равноценно остановке системы (`shutdown -h now`).

Comment: не, не всех файлов, а вот тока конкретных. они висят в памяти и мешают другим.

Comment: Так может, Вам нужно понять, как прерывать процесс, открывший тот или иной файл?

Comment: Возможно да. Только вот один процесс работает с несколькими файлами, а если убить процесс, то закроются все файлы, а не конкретные.

Comment: Ну вот представьте. Процесс имеет открытые файловые дескрипторы. Вы находите способы их закрыть (все или только конкретные). Далее процесс пытается обратиться к этим дескрипторам. В нормальной программе возникает исключительная ситуация и с процессом может произойти что угодно, вплоть до его закрытия (в лучшем случае) или некорректной работы. И?

Comment: а как же мне тогда закрыть только конкретные файлы, чтобы не возникало некорректной работы? вот в чем мой вопрос

Comment: Боюсь, что никак.

Comment: А каким способом закрыть файловые дескрипторы процесса?